# Does NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections limit the number of concurrent connections to an endpoint or…?

Tags: wcf

Book Essential WCF claims that `NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections` limits the number of  connections to an endpoint. Thus if property is set to value of 10, then only 10 concurrent connections will be allowed to that endpoint.

But the following blog http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/181 claims this property this property doesn’t limit the number of concurrent connections, but instead only specifies max number of connections that will be cached and reused by another channel:

> MaxConnections for TCP is not a hard
>   and fast limit, but rather a knob on
>   the connections that we will cache in
>   our connection pool. That is, if you
>   set MaxConnections=2, you can still
>   open 4 client channels on the same
>   factory simultaneously. However, when
>   you close all of these channels, we
>   will only keep two of these
>   connections around (subject to
>   IdleTimeout of course) for future
>   channel usage. This helps performance
>   in cases where you are creating and
>   disposing client channels. This knob
>   will also apply to the equivalent
>   usage on the server-side as well (that
>   is, when a server-side channel is
>   closed, if we have less than
>   MaxConnections in our server-side pool
>   we will initiate I/O to look for
>   another new client channel).

So which is true?

EDIT:

> First of all, you mean NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections, right?

Yes, thank you ...  I've corrected the typo

> See official docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections.aspx and especially http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx - the behavior is actually different depending if it's the server or the client, but in no case is it a hard limit on the number of connections. (On the client, it's a limit on the connections that are pooled, and on the server it's a limit on connections that haven't been accepted yet by the ServiceModel layer).

a) I assume by “pooled” you mean number of connection that will be reused by other channels. But the blog says this is the case for both client and the server, while if I understand you correctly, you’re saying on server it means number of connections waiting to be accepted by ServiceModel layer?

Thus if property is set to 10, then only 10 connections will be allowed to wait to be accepted and if another connection tries to wait, it will immediately be rejected?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you mean `NetTcpBinding.MaxConnections`, right?

See official docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections.aspx and especially http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx - the behavior is actually different depending if it's the server or the client, but in no case is it a hard limit on the number of connections. (On the client, it's a limit on the connections that are pooled, and on the server it's a limit on connections that haven't been accepted yet by the ServiceModel layer).

Comment: "on the server it's a limit on connections that haven't been accepted yet by the ServiceModel layer)" Isn't this limit actually set by ListenBackLog property?